# How to create a back button in a view controller to go to parent view controller

Tags: ios, back-button, childviewcontroller

hi I have a view controller with a container and in the container a child view with a collection view when the user taps the collection view cell it sends me to detail view controller but now what i want to do is to add a back button in my detail view controller which sends me to the parentViewController

[image]

Comment: This is what `UINavigationController` is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case 1** : Unwind Segue

This will work perfect according to your situation:

[iOS Unwind Segue](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/)

Unwind Segues give you a way to “unwind” the navigation stack and specify a destination to go back to.

**Case 2** : PopToRootViewController

If you Parent view is also your Root view controller, then you can easily get back using `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES`.

Create own back button add it to navigation bar with method `backButtonTouch`.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backButtonTouch:)];
```

Add above code into `viewDidLoad`.

```
-(void)backButtonTouch:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to customise the back button, first hide the navigation bar

   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
2. Now add a button, and create its touchUpInside event, in that event pop the controller

   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

On Back button action, add this line:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will move you to `rootViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to go back to parent view controller

```
 - (IBAction)ActionbtnBack:(id)sender {
        int flag = 0;
        for (UIViewController *controller in [[self.navigationController.viewControllers reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]) {
            NSLog(@"> %@",[controller class]);
            if ([controller isKindOfClass:[YourParentviewcontroller class]]) {
                flag=1;
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                                      animated:YES];
                break;
            }
            else if ([controller isKindOfClass:[YourParentviewcontroller class]]) {
                flag=1;
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                                      animated:YES];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            YourParentviewcontroller *MoreVc = [[YourParentviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"parentViewcontrollerIdentifier" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:MoreVc animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

[image]