# How to pass the value between viewcontrollerB into viiewcontrollerA using push segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I'm having two view controller A and B. when click button on view controllerA it will navigate to view controllerB and their is a **tableview with textlabel**,when i click on tableviewcell i want to navigate back into viewcontrollerA and want to **pass that textlabel value back to viewcontrollerA**

Comment: Use the concept of Unwind segues to post data back : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714845/how-to-create-a-back-button-in-a-view-controller-to-go-to-parent-view-controller/34714903#34714903

Comment: Check my answer and reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `push seque` is the worst way, reason you increase the memory in your stack trace.

you can do this in multiple ways, search once in google you get multiple answer related to this

1. UnWind Segue
2. Protocols & delegates
3. local database method
4. using Singleton class.
5. Using bean object method.
6. using Plist
7. finally go for NSUserDefault

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample using Protocols and Delegates, as follows:

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ColorsTableViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <ColorsDelegate>

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textDataLabel;
- (IBAction)goButtonTapped:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)sendColor:(NSString *)colorName{
    self.textDataLabel.text = colorName;
}

- (IBAction)goButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    ColorsTableViewController *colorsTableViewController=(ColorsTableViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"colorTableIdentifier"];
    colorsTableViewController.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:colorsTableViewController animated:YES];
}
@end
```

### ColorsTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ColorsDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)sendColor:(NSString *)colorName;

@end

@interface ColorsTableViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ColorsDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

### ColorsTableViewController.m

```
#import "ColorsTableViewController.h"

@interface ColorsTableViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *colorsTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *colorsArray;

@end

@implementation ColorsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.colorsArray = @[@"Red",@"Green",@"Blue",@"Brown",@"Yellow"];

    [self.colorsTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"colorCell"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.colorsArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *myCell = [self.colorsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"colorCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *myTextLabel = [myCell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    if(!myTextLabel)
    {
        myTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, CGRectGetWidth(myCell.frame), CGRectGetHeight(myCell.frame))];
        myTextLabel.tag = 100;
    }
    myTextLabel.text = self.colorsArray[indexPath.row];
    [myCell.contentView addSubview:myTextLabel];
    return myCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     UITableViewCell *myCell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.colorsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     UILabel *myTextLabel = [myCell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    if(myTextLabel)
    {
        [_delegate sendColor:myTextLabel.text];
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Here is my GitHub Link, please download and check:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/sendDataBack