# How can I skip a ViewController when dismissing from navigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Say that you have some ViewControllers like:

```
A --> B --> C --> X --> D
```

Where `X` is some sort of perpetual menu that can be opened from everywhere. All of those are plugged to a `NavigationController`, so for going back I would do something like:

`func leftNavButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
  navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}`

However if I do that from `D`, I want to go back to `C`, not `X`. I tried dismissing the menu before opening the next `ViewController` but that doesn't seem to work very well.

Any ideas?

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714845/how-to-create-a-back-button-in-a-view-controller-to-go-to-parent-view-controller/34714903#34714903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the view controller stack to find your VC and pop to it

```
if let vcStack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
        {
            for vc in vcStack {
                        if vc.isKindOfClass(MyVC)
                        {                           
                            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
                            break
                        }
                    }
        }
```