# Push several ViewControllers and trigger method from the last one, dismissing all before

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my problem.

I have `ViewController` A (let's call it only `A`).

 I push from `A` to `B`, which is custom camera controller.
When I take picture, I present modally controller `C` which has two buttons, one for confirm and one for going back.

 If back button is tapped, it goes back to `B` controller.

 If confirm button is tapped, `C` should trigger delegate method to `A`, and then dismiss `C` and `B`, but without animation so dismissing `B` won't be noticed.

**Questions:**

 1. How to achieve the above described scenario? `A` needs to be delegate to `C`, so how to do that? Also should I use unwinding?

Reminder: A -> push -> B -> modal -> C

Comment: Why not use unwind segue ??

Comment: I was thinking of that, but am I be able to update A from C?

Comment: I believe so lemme try and update u :)

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714845/how-to-create-a-back-button-in-a-view-controller-to-go-to-parent-view-controller/34714903#34714903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of UnwindSegue,

You can declare a method in VC A as

```
@IBAction func unWindToVCA(segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

In VC C storyboard , you can control drag from viewController to exit and you will prompted with a popover which will have a list of all the unwind segues you have declared before. Select the unWindToVCA.

Now select the segue and assign a reusable identifier to it as shown in pic below :)

[image]

Finally whenever you want to go back to VC1, call

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToVC1", sender: nil)
```

Now in VCA you can get the data from VC C using,

```
@IBAction func unWindToVCA(segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {
       let c = segue.source
       //access c's data and update A
}
```

I have followed your hierarchy of VC's as well
VC A -> push VC B -> modal -> VC C

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do same functionality with just pass reference of B to C controller

Controller B Code

```
class BViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var controllerA : ViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func confirmEventCallFromC() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    }

    @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CVC", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "CVC" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! CViewController
            vc.controllerB = self
        }

    }

}
```

And Controller C Code is like this

```
class CViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var controllerB : BViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func confirmBtnClick(_ sender: Any) {
        controllerB.confirmEventCallFromC()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. This also works, but it is more recommended to use unwinding segues.